# android google maps issue

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

In the program below i am trying to use google map from the following example http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html , i have followed exactly all the steps in the example but some how i am not able t execute it the APP closes down .

Below is my code.Let me know what am i doing wrong here

```
package ShowMap.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class ShowmapActivity extends MapActivity {
private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

}
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}

   }
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/mapview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="0YjDTTmg77Hdf9GVv26GW1123452v4ssZererHikVw"
             />
```

Android manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="ShowMap.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ShowmapActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


</manifest>
```

`EDIT:This is the logcat trace`

```
     07-18 15:20:46.065: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(469): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     07-18 15:20:46.096: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(469): CheckJNI is ON
     07-18 15:20:50.572: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(472): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     07-18 15:20:50.572: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(472): CheckJNI is ON
     07-18 15:20:54.486: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(469): --- registering native functions ---
     07-18 15:20:54.511: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(472): --- registering native functions ---
     07-18 15:21:09.085: DEBUG/dalvikvm(472): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@pm.jar@classes.dex)
     07-18 15:21:10.252: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(469): Shutting down VM
     07-18 15:21:10.266: INFO/AndroidRuntime(469): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
     07-18 15:21:10.305: DEBUG/dalvikvm(469): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
     07-18 15:21:13.498: DEBUG/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXPLICIT freed 114 objects / 5848 bytes in 1347ms
     07-18 15:21:13.916: DEBUG/PackageParser(66): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl20199.tmp
     07-18 15:21:14.051: WARN/PackageParser(66): Unknown element under <manifest>: uses-library at /data/app/vmdl20199.tmp Binary XML file line #7
     07-18 15:21:15.378: INFO/PackageManager(66): Removing non-system package:ShowMap.com
     07-18 15:21:15.378: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package ShowMap.com uid=10040
     07-18 15:21:15.835: DEBUG/PackageManager(66): Scanning package ShowMap.com
     07-18 15:21:15.845: INFO/PackageManager(66): Package ShowMap.com codePath changed from /data/app/ShowMap.com-1.apk to /data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
     07-18 15:21:15.867: INFO/PackageManager(66): /data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk changed; unpacking
     07-18 15:21:15.935: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk' ---
     07-18 15:21:16.495: DEBUG/dalvikvm(485): DexOpt: load 75ms, verify 122ms, opt 10ms
     07-18 15:21:16.515: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk' (success) ---
     07-18 15:21:16.555: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package ShowMap.com uid=10040
     07-18 15:21:16.555: WARN/PackageManager(66): Code path for pkg : ShowMap.com changing from /data/app/ShowMap.com-1.apk to /data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk
     07-18 15:21:16.575: WARN/PackageManager(66): Resource path for pkg : ShowMap.com changing from /data/app/ShowMap.com-1.apk to /data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk
     07-18 15:21:16.595: DEBUG/PackageManager(66):   Activities: ShowMap.com.ShowmapActivity
     07-18 15:21:16.875: INFO/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ShowMap.com-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ShowMap.com-2.apk@classes.dex
     07-18 15:21:16.875: DEBUG/PackageManager(66): New package installed in /data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk
     07-18 15:21:17.187: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package ShowMap.com uid=10040
     07-18 15:21:17.610: DEBUG/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13050 objects / 728192 bytes in 342ms
     07-18 15:21:20.477: DEBUG/dalvikvm(123): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1150 objects / 59528 bytes in 2120ms
     07-18 15:21:27.735: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(66): no available voice recognition services found
     07-18 15:21:30.515: DEBUG/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3973 objects / 218952 bytes in 589ms
     07-18 15:21:31.946: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ShowMap.com-1.apk@classes.dex
     07-18 15:21:32.034: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(472): Shutting down VM
     07-18 15:21:32.045: DEBUG/dalvikvm(472): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
     07-18 15:21:32.085: INFO/AndroidRuntime(472): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
     07-18 15:21:33.235: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(491): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     07-18 15:21:33.235: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(491): CheckJNI is ON
     07-18 15:21:33.735: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(491): --- registering native functions ---
     07-18 15:21:35.950: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=ShowMap.com/.ShowmapActivity }
     07-18 15:21:37.315: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(491): Shutting down VM
     07-18 15:21:37.324: INFO/AndroidRuntime(491): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
     07-18 15:21:37.366: DEBUG/dalvikvm(491): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
     07-18 15:21:39.699: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Start proc ShowMap.com for activity ShowMap.com/.ShowmapActivity: pid=498 uid=10040 gids={3003}
     07-18 15:21:43.026: WARN/dalvikvm(498): Unable to resolve superclass of LShowMap/com/ShowmapActivity; (20)
     07-18 15:21:43.026: WARN/dalvikvm(498): Link of class 'LShowMap/com/ShowmapActivity;' failed
     07-18 15:21:43.096: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(498): Shutting down VM
     07-18 15:21:43.096: WARN/dalvikvm(498): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ShowMap.com/ShowMap.com.ShowmapActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ShowMap.com.ShowmapActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk]
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ShowMap.com.ShowmapActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ShowMap.com-2.apk]
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
     07-18 15:21:43.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(498):     ... 11 more
     07-18 15:21:43.364: WARN/ActivityManager(66):   Force finishing activity ShowMap.com/.ShowmapActivity
     07-18 15:21:43.915: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44f9e8b8 ShowMap.com/.ShowmapActivity}
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you put logcat trace?

Comment: I have posted the logcat tRACE IN edit

Comment: Are you executing the code on a real device, or a virtual device ? If your using an AVD make sure its Target is a Google API & not an Android x.y

Comment: I am trying it on an emulator and have choosen the target as google API version 2.2 SDK version 8 and also on a real device..

Comment: I don't think your Logcat trace is showing the real error, Sntpclient is just retrieving network time AFAIK, nothing to do with Google Maps. Can you try another logcat capture ?

Comment: Yes i have posted a new logcat trace .Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not only the AVD but also the target of your code must be set on Google API and not Android API. Check this in your default.properties file.
If it's currently set to Android API, you can change it like this way:
Select your project folder > properties > android > In the project build target select the Google API for your API level. Save All and it's done!

Have nice development!