# What does the 'L' letter mean at the beginning of some logcat urls/uri's? Is it a bug?

Tags: java, android, logcat, dalvik

In a different question I posted (I figured out the answer to that question by now), I noticed a mention of 'Landroid' in the logcat.

My original question:
[Android app starts slow, but works fine after that slow start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501650/android-app-starts-slow-but-works-fine-after-that-slow-start)

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat21$SharedElementCallbackImpl;' failed
```

After searching on SO I noticed other people also have logcats with an L at the start of a URL (URI?) that doesn't seem to make sense.

[Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738398/unable-to-resolve-superclass-of-lnet)

```
W/dalvikvm(7116): Link of class 'Lnet/appcelent/commonlibrary/Lib_MailSender;' failed
```

[android google maps issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730616/android-google-maps-issue)

```
WARN/dalvikvm(498): Link of class 'LShowMap/com/ShowmapActivity;' failed
```

So I wonder, does that letter L stand for something, or is that a typo somewhere in how the logcat is created? Or is it indicative of a mistake I made myself somewhere?

Also I don't understand what the logcat line means, so that didn't help with my original question either.

Comment: Only seconds question on SO, maybe I'm missing something, but why would this question get -5?

Comment: This seems like a valid question to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internally Java represents type names as strings: (I don't know why these rules were chosen)

- `I` is `int`, `J` is `long`, other primitive types have other single-letter names.
- Object types are `L<classname>;` where `<classname>` is the full class name with `.` replaced by `/`
- Sticking `[` at the front gets you an array of that thing (can have multiple `[`s for an array of arrays)

`Lnet/appcelent/commonlibrary/Lib_MailSender;` means the class `net.appcelent.commonlibrary.Lib_MailSender`. The only bug here is that the message shows the internal name instead of the "user-friendly" class name.

Comment: Thank you. Clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

it came from java byte code, L is prefix for class name.

See 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3
for more details about all possible prefixes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes it's short answer, but I wrote that L means class name, which is answer to what 'L' mean.

Comment: I can see both of your points.  Though if possibly just fluff out your answer with a little more explanation if possible and then everyone is happy.

Comment: @Jesus : You are correct, My mistake, but answer could include some more explanations, especially when including a link that explains details. I deleted my comment.